# On a certain proportion concerning sets and permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $X$ be a finite set and let $f$ and $g$ be permutations with $f\ne g\ne f^{-1}$.
Can you show that the proportion of subsets $S$ with $|S\cap f(S)|=|S\cap g(S) |$ is at most $3/4$?

In other words
$$\frac{|\{S\subseteq X\mid|S\cap f(S)|=|S\cap g(S) | \} |}{|\{S\subseteq X\}|}\leq\frac{3}{4} \cdot 2^{|X|}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

True, of course (except the correct exception was given by Robert Israel, not by the OP), but nearly trivial.

Let us consider all vectors $\delta=(\delta_1,\dots,\delta_n)$ consisting of $0$ and $1$. The question is just how often it can happen that $F(\delta)=\langle\delta,A\delta\rangle=0$ where the matrix $A=P-Q$ is the difference of the permutation matrices corresponding to $f$ and $g$. The claim is that either $A$ is antisymmetric, in which case the scalar product is always $0$, or $F(\delta)$ does not vanish for at least $1/4$ of possible choices of $\delta$. Indeed, if $a=A_{ij}+A_{ji}\ne 0$ for some $i\ne j$, then with all $\delta_k,k\ne i,j$ fixed, we can treat the scalar product as a function $F'(\delta_i,\delta_j)$ and write
$$
F'(1,1)+F'(0,0)-F'(1,0)-F'(0,1)=a\ne 0
$$ 
so at least one of $4$ choices should produce a non-zero value.
If $A_{ij}+A_{ji}=0$ for all $i\ne j$, then $F(\delta)=\sum_i A_{ii}\delta_i$, so if some $A_{ii}\ne 0$, we can do the same trick fixing all $\delta_k, k\ne i$ and see that one of every two choices of $\delta_i$ should produce a non-zero value.

Thus, the exceptions are exactly the permutations for which $P-Q$ is antisymmetric. Now let $I$ be the set of rows of $P-Q$ that vanish identically and let $J$ be the set of columns corresponding to these rows in each of the permutations $P$ and $Q$. Then $P-Q$ has non-zero rows $I^c$ but the non-zero columns can be only $J^c$, so, by the antysimmetry, $I^c=J^c$ and $I=J$. Thus, we found a common invariant set $I$ for $f$ and $g$ on which $f=g$ and its complement is also invariant. Moreover, if we forget about $I$, then $P$ consists of $1$'s and $-Q$ of $-1$'s, so $P-Q$ can be antisymmetric only if $Q=P^T$, i.e., if $g=f^{-1}$ on $I^c$.

Answer (score 2):

Not true.  Try $f = (1,2,3)(4,5,6)$ and $g = (1,2,3)(4,6,5)$. Then $|S \cap f(S)| = |S \cap g(S)|$ for all subsets of $\{1,\ldots,6\}$.

Comment: $|S \cap f(S)| = |S \cap g(S)|$ holds for all $S$, whenever $f,g$ induce the same partition on $\{1,2,\dots ,n\}$ in their cycle decomposition. So the OP probably wants to rule this out rather than just $f\neq g\neq f^{-1}$.

Comment: Actually, this holds only if the cycle lengths of f and g are small (less than 4). For example, take two permutations on seven elements. Some two element sets are moved to disjoint sets under one cycle and not under the other.  Gerhard "Seven Is Not Always Small" Paseman, 2019.12.18.

Comment: I think the correct generalization of my example is that there is $A \subseteq \{1,\ldots, n\}$ invariant under $f$ and $g$ such that $\left. f\right|_A = \left. g\right|_A$ and $\left. f \right|_{A^c} = \left. g^{-1}\right|_{A^c}$.